# Non-global region not rendering on auth or account pages when query string present

Tags: bigcommerce

We have a non-global region defined in the header component which is included on all pages via the base layout file.

When a widget is added to that region via the editor on the /login.php page, the widget is rendered. If you navigate to a page with a query string e.g. /login.php?action=reset_password the widget isn’t rendered and you’re unable to edit that page via the Page Builder.

If you use a global region for this, it’s fine, the widget renders in the region on all pages. My issue is that I needed to only add the widget to account related pages, and most of those including the logged in account pages use query strings.

Does any know why this behaves this way?

I’ve created a work-around by defining a global region which only renders when templates contain “auth” or “account” in their path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're experiencing the side effects of a bug. I was able to locate a similar issue, on an internal ticket. However, I'm not positive that it's 1:1 with what you're describing. If you haven't already, I'd recommend you to [contact our technical support team](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/#contact) to report this, so they can verify that and log appropriately.